# ¿Como evitar el error al volver a la página anterior después de un submit?

Tags: formularios, post

Tengo una duda en los envíos de formularios.

1. Envío un form por `POST`.
2. La nueva página se carga con la información requerida.
3. Visito otra página
4. Hago `click` atrás en el navegador para ir a la web anterior (la que
   contenía los datos del `POST`).

Cuando hago esto, la web me marca un error "*No se puede acceder a este sitio web*".

Me gustaría solucionar este error de alguna forma para mejorar la usabilidad.
¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo podría solventarlo?

Comment: crea un `REST` con metodo `GET`, con el mismo nombre para que no te bote el error

Comment: ¿Como haría eso?

Comment: tendrias que publicar `código`, puesto que `No se puede acceder a este sitio web`, parece ser una restriccion tuya, ya que el error comun de volver a un formulario que mostraba datos de un `POST` es que no existe tal valor, por ejemplo: `$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];` es que `nombre` no existe en las variables de entrada, si fuera `$nombre=$_GET["nombre"];` , los parametros que pasaste aparecirian en la `URL` así `--/ruta?nombre=anto&edad=5`, con la cual no saldria error ya que existen dichos datos en la entrada

Answer (score 1):

#### El problema

Cuando un formulario web es enviado a un servidor a través de una solicitud **HTTP POST**, y el usuario que intenta refrescar la respuesta del servidor puede hacer que el contenido de la solicitud **HTTP POST** original vuelva a enviarse, lo que podría producir resultados no deseados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### La solución

Una solución es implementar [**Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), también conocido como **Redirect After Post**

> **PRG** es un patrón de diseño de desarrollo web que impide algunos envíos de formularios duplicados, creando una interfaz más intuitiva para los agentes de usuario (usuarios).
>
> [...] en lugar de retornar directamente a una página web, la operación POST devuelve un comando de redireccionamiento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Ejemplo en `PHP`

- Archivo del formulario:

  ```
  <form action="busqueda.php" method="POST">
    <input name="search"/>
    <button>Buscar</button>
  </form>
  ```
- Archivo de proceso de datos:

  ```
  <?php
  // ... Código sin imprimir datos de salida ...

  // Redirección
  header('Location: resultado.php');
  die();
  ```
- Archivo de resultado

  ```
  <h1>Resultado de la busqueda</h1>
  <!-- Código -->
  ```

---

Referencias:

- [Wikipedia - Post/Redirect/Get](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)