# Evitar login nuevamente, tras presionar botón de atrás del navegador

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

Cuando inicio sesión, me logueo correctamente, la cuestión es que cuando le doy click al botón de atrás del navegador me manda al formulario de login, como hago para evitar esto? 
aquí el código de login:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['submit_login'])) {
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'conexion.php';
session_start();


$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
// $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if (empty($user) && empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = '*Los campos no pueden estar vacíos';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../login_index.php?error=empty-field-campos-vacios');
     exit();
}elseif (empty($user)) {
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'El campo usuario no puede estar vacío';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../login_index.php?error=empty-user-invalid');
    exit();
}elseif (empty($password)) {
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'La contraseña no puede estar vacía';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../login_index.php?error=empty-password-invalid');
    exit();
}else{
    $sql = "select * from user where username = ? or email = ? ";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        echo "<script>alert('Error en la conexion de la base de datos');window.location:'../login_index.php';</script>";
        exit();
    }
    else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $user, $user);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $password_check = password_verify($password, $row['password']);
    if ($password_check == false) {
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'Error al ingresar la contraseña';
    $_SESSION['color-error'] = 'danger';
    header('location:../login_index.php?error=password-invalid-database-error');
        exit();

    }elseif ($password_check == true) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['username'];
    // $_SESSION['nombre_usuario'] = $row['username'];
    echo "<script>alert('Iniciando sesión :)');window.location='../portal.php';</script>";
    exit(); 

    }
  }
}
```

}
}

cuando la sesión existe correctamente me envia a portal.php
ya aqui es cuando estoy logueado y le doy al boton de navegación atras me manda al formulario de login, no quiero eso, que hago?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
 header('location:login_index.php');
 exit();
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Dos caminos: a) no pelear con la navegación y que, al aterrizar en el login, la página valide si hay sesión válida y te redireccione de nuevo [ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108708/how-to-prevent-browser-from-going-back-to-login-form-page-once-user-is-logged-in); b) meterte con el evento

Comment: Como dice @Alfabravo todas las páginas deben validar que haya una sesión activa, incluyendo la de login. Si el usuario echa para atrás, las variables de sesión van a estar seteadas y podrías mandarle un mensaje al usuario de, que no sea pende... que la sesión ya está activa y que si desea cambiar de usuario, que cierre la sesión actual.

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291172/16597) te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 6):

Yo utilizo esta función para evitar el evento del retroceso, espero te sirva.

```js
function deshabilitaRetroceso(){
    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
    window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="";}
}
```

```html
<body onload="deshabilitaRetroceso()">
```

Answer (score 0):

**INTENTA COLOCANDO ESE SCRIPT EN LA PARTE INFERIOR DE TU LOGIN**

- Ese script te redireccionará al login inicial.

  ```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <!-- Title Page -->
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <form>
        <!-- Username -->
        <label for="name">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="name"><br>
        <!-- Password -->
        <label for="username">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password"><br><br>
        <!-- Submit Button -->
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>

  <script type= text/javascript>
  /* AQUI COLOCAMOS LA URL BASE, ES DECIR LA QUE TE LLEVA AL LOGIN*/
    if(window.history.replaceState) {
      window.history.replaceState(null,null,'<?php echo base_url();?>');
    }
  </script>
  ```

- Elemento de lista

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).