# Después de insertar datos desde un formulario en PHP a MySQL, se siguen insertando registros cada vez que actualizo el navegador

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Disculpen la pregunta, soy principiante en esto:

Después de insertar datos desde un formulario en PHP a MySQL,  se siguen insertando los mismos registros cada vez que actualizo el navegador, ¿cómo puedo arreglar eso?

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion2.php';
?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="contacts">
      <h1 align="center">SISTEMA DE TRAMITE ONLINE</h1>
      <ul>
        <li align="center"> I.E. "NUESTRA SEÑORA DEL CARMEN"</li>

        <li align="center">JAUJA</li>
        <br>

       <div align="center"><img src="imagenes/logotipo.png" alt="IE.Nuestra Señora del Carmen" class="img-circle"></div>
        <li align="center">"Paz y bien"</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="form" method="post">
      <h2>Ingrese los datos de su tramite</h2>
      <form action="registro.php" method="post">
        <p align="center">
          <label for="">Nombres</label>
          <input type="text" name="xNombre">
        </p>
        <p  align="center">
          <label for="">Apellidos</label>
           <input type="text" name="xApellido">
        </p>
        <p  align="center">
          <label for="">Correo Electronico</label>
          <input type="text" name="xCorreo">
        </p>
        <p align="center">
          <label for="">Celular</label>
           <input type="text" name="xCelular">
        </p>
        <p  align="center">
           <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Area</label>
          <select name="xArea">
          <option value="">Seleccione Grado</option>
          <option value="PRIMERO">Dirección</option>
          <option value="SEGUNDO">Sub-Dirección</option>
          <option value="TERCERO">Administración</option>
          <option value="CUARTO">Secretaria</option>
          <option value="QUINTO">Otro</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      <p  align="center">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Tipo de documento</label>
          <select name="xDocumento">
          <option value="">Seleccione un tipo</option>
          <option value="PRIMERO">Oficio</option>
          <option value="SEGUNDO">Solicitud</option>
          <option value="TERCERO">Invitacion</option>
          <option value="CUARTO">Notificación</option>
          <option value="QUINTO">Otro</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p align="center">
        
       </p>       
        <p  align="center">
          <label for="">Escriba su solicitud</label>
          <textarea name="xDetalles" id="" cols="30" rows="7"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p align="center">
          <input align="center" type="submit" name="btnconsulta" class="btn btn-danger" value="Registrar">
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
$boton1="";
$boton2="";
$boton3="";
$btnconsulta="";

if (isset($_POST["xNombre"], $_POST["xApellido"], $_POST["xCorreo"]) and $_POST["xCelular"] !="" and $_POST["xArea"]!="" and $_POST["xDocumento"]!="" and $_POST["xDetalles"]!=""){
    require_once 'conexion2.php';  
    $NOM=$_POST["xNombre"];
    $AP=$_POST["xApellido"];
    $COR=$_POST["xCorreo"];
    $CEL=$_POST["xCelular"];
    $AREA=$_POST["xArea"];  
    $DOC=$_POST["xDocumento"];
    $DETALLE=$_POST["xDetalles"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO expediente (Apellidos,Nombres,Correo,Celular,Area,Tipo,Detalle) VALUES ('$AP','$NOM','$COR','$CEL','$AREA','$DOC','$DETALLE')";
    if(mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)){
  mysqli_close($conexion);
$btnconsulta="";
} else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conexion);
}
}


    ?>
    
 </body>
 </html>
```

¿Cómo hago para evitar que se sigan agregando más registros al pulsar sobre el botón actualizar del navegador?

Por otro lado me gustaría que me digan si hay algo que podría mejorar de mi código. Muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: El código php que tienes al final de la página se esta ejecutando cada vez que haces el llamado a la página, ese código debería estar en registro.php o sea se ejecutaría solo cuando haces el submit del formulario.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como evitar el error al volver a la página anterior después de un submit?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290520/como-evitar-el-error-al-volver-a-la-p%c3%a1gina-anterior-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-submit)

Answer (score 0):

probablemente las propiedades de post se envían junto con la recarga de la página, deberías separar la lógica en formato cliente servidor, en tu caso el php se ejecuta siempre que recargas la página, captura variables post por lo que isset no hace su trabajo validando la existencia, si quisieras dejarlo así y parcharlo deberías agregar una función que resetee el formulario para que isset no de true

más o menos así

```
document.getElementById("id-form").reset();
```

esto se ejecuta después de agregar el registro en bd

Comment: Puedes explicarme un poco mas, soy principiante en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Ese es un problema típico de cuando la función de INSERT está en el mismo archivo que tiene el formulario HTML.

Hay formas JS para solucionar el problema, pero una técnica **versión backend** sería algo como:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['tstamp'])) {
    // Declarar esto cuando se hace el login del usuario
    $_SESSION['tstamp'] = 0.0;
}

$tstm = microtime(true);
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="tstamp" value="<?php echo $tstm;?>">
    <input type="text" name="xNombre">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["xNombre"])) {
    $tstm = $_POST['tstamp'];
    $nombre = $_POST['xNombre'];
    if($_SESSION['tstamp'] != $tstm) {
        $_SESSION['tstamp'] = $tstm;
        echo "<p>Se insertara en la BD: $nombre</p>";
        // [...] Rutina de insertar en BD
    } else {
        echo '<p>[ERROR] Estos datos ya han sido insertado</p>';
    }
}
```

Es un formulario reducido para entenderlo mejor.

Cuando se carga el formulario, se le asigna a un campo `hidden` el tiempo [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.microtime.php). Al momento de insertar se compara si la variable de sesión tiene el mismo valor que la del campo `hidden`. Si no es así, entonces se actualiza la variable de sesión con ese valor y se hace el **INSERT**.

Al darle **F5** o **refresh**, el navegador vuelve a enviar los datos que ya tiene en memoria, omitiendo los del formulario, por eso volverá a enviar el mismo `$tstm` y este será igual al de la variable de sesión. En ese momento entrará en el `else` enviando el mensaje de que ya el registro ha sido insertado.

Comment: Eso funcionaria si tengo implementado mi Login, pero aun no lo tengo implementado, ¿como  seria en ese caso?

Answer (score 0):

1. Te recomiendo llamar a un script diferente cuando envíes el formulario. Que tu html se encargue de mostrar el formulario y un script independiente verifique y realice las operaciones necesarias.
2. Cuando se haya realizado el INSERT reenvía al usuario a una nueva página para que así no se sigan enviando los datos del formulario al actualizar la página.
   Puedes usar la función `header('Location: url-ejemplo.com')`.

- [Función header() manual PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php).
- Como ejemplo puedes enviar al usuario a una página que indique que el registro se ha realizado correctamente, junto a un enlace a la página de registro.