# Al presionar F5 se vuelve enviar un formulario de registro con php

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente formulario con el que registro en mi BD y con isset(boton) estoy validando cuando se presione el botón submit:

```
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Fecha de envio:</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$evento["id_evento"];?>" name="txtIdEvento">
        <input type="date" name="txtFechaEnvio" required>
        <hr>
        <label>cantidad de correos Enviados:</label>
        <input type="number" name="txtCantidad" required>
        <hr>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Registrar" name="btnRegistrarEnvio">
    </form>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST["btnRegistrarEnvio"])){
  $objEnvio=new EnviosEvento($id,$_POST["txtFechaEnvio"],$_POST["txtCantidad"]);
  $objEnvio->registrarEnvio();
}
```

el realiza el registro correctamente y luego recarga la página dejando los input en blanco pero **si por si se llega a presionar F5 o recargar la página el nuevamente toma como si se hubiera presionado el botón de registro y envía los mismos datos anteriores para registrarlos**

Como puedo evitar este comportamiento  o que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede cuando el formulario está en la misma página que la lógica para insertar en la Base de Datos. Existen diversas técnicas, una de ellas es, por ejemplo, obligar a la página a redireccionarse a si misma para limpiar el contenido de POST:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

También se podría hacer vía JavaScript.

---

Otra técnica es, si usas sesiones, puedes tener una variable para testear si los formularios se han vuelto a enviar. En el login agregas una variable adicional `$_SESSION[t_inserted] = 0.0;`.
Ahora en el archivo en cuestión:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if ($_SESSION['t_inserted'] == $_POST['tstamp']) {
        // Error, ya has insertado este registro
        // ...
    } else {
        $_SESSION['t_inserted'] = $_POST['tstamp']; // Actualizar la variable
        // Instrucciones para insertar el registro
        // ...
    }
}
```

Y en el formulario

```
<input type="hidden" name="tstamp" value="<?php echo microtime(true);?>">
```

Lecturas recomendadas: [Referencia 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/382829/80870) | [Referencia 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8335828/1545868) | [Referencia 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40113251/1545868)