# ¿Como puedo saber si se refresco / recargo una pagina, o se pulso la tecla F5?

Tags: php, post, refresh

Lo que quiero saber es si posible detectar si se recarga/refresca una pagina, ya sea por el botón del navegador o al pulsar la tecla F5.

¿Por qué lo quiero?
Tengo varias paginas con formularios, los cuales al enviar información muestran los mensajes de guardado en la base de datos, hasta acá, todo correcto, pero si se recarga la pagina, intenta realizar nuevamente el guardado en la base de datos.

Con algunos formularios es fácil evitar esto, ya que hay un condicional que valida si el registro ya existe, pero con otros no es posible, debido a que una persona puede guardar la misma información muchas veces y si en el caso, se recarga la pagina X cantidad de veces, esta misma cantidad se guardara en la base de datos.

¿Cuál es la idea?
Detectar si se recargo la pagina, para cargar una función, que envié a una pagina distinta y vuelva nuevamente a la pagina en la que estaba el usuario y así limpiar el $_POST y evitar envió de la información.

¿Por qué no simplemente limpiar el $_POST?
Fue inicialmente mi idea y lo intente por medio unset(), asignando un valor en blanco a $_POST entre otras cosas.

De igual forma si alguno sabe como vaciar (empty) $_POST, también es una solución viable y creo mucho más efectiva y más sencilla.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se ha contestado otras veces: [Al presionar F5 se vuelve enviar formulario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/529038/80870)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Al presionar F5 se vuelve enviar un formulario de registro con php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529023/al-presionar-f5-se-vuelve-enviar-un-formulario-de-registro-con-php)

Comment: Saludos.
En verdad estuve viendo el código de las respuestas que me dan, pero no me funcionan ya que hay otros factores que intervienen, aun así, he estado buscando otra solución basándome en esas información. hago pruebas de a ratos, puesto que el tema no es una prioridad alta, pero si es una mejora.

Actualizare en el momento en que tenga algún avance.

Answer (score 0):

cuando envíes el formulario puedes enviar una variable formularioOK por ejemplo que sea true, en un refresh esa variable no se recibirá y sabrás que es un F5

saludos

Comment: Hola Alejandro, bienvenido, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!