# ¿Como evitar que al recargar una pagina, la imagen del servidor se vuelva a enviar a la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas noches Colegas,

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un pequeño código en PHP para poder subir una imagen a una base de datos MySQL. La imagen se almacena en el servidor de WAMP, y se envía a una tabla en la Base de Datos, el problema es que al recargar la página, este imagen se vuelve a enviar, y así repetidamente dependiendo de la cantidad de veces que recargue la página, he intentado solucionar esto con el método "unlink" de PHP, pero no he logrado solucionarlo.

A continuación comparto el código donde realizo esto:

```
<?php 
                if(isset($_REQUEST['guardar'])){
                    if(isset($_FILES['foto']['name'])){
                        $tipoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['type'];
                        $permitido=array("image/png","image/jpeg");
                        if( in_array($tipoArchivo,$permitido) ==false ){
                            die("Archivo no permitido");
                        }
                        $nombreArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['name'];
                        $tamanoArchivo=$_FILES['foto']['size'];
                        $imagenSubida=fopen($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'],'r');
                        $imagenCarpeta=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
                        $binariosImagen=fread($imagenSubida,$tamanoArchivo);
                        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","base_prueba","3308");
                        $binariosImagen=mysqli_escape_string($con,$binariosImagen);
                        $query="INSERT INTO imagenes (nombre,imagen,tipo) values 
                                ('".$nombreArchivo."','".$binariosImagen."','".$tipoArchivo."')";
                        $res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                        $ruta = 'img/imagenes_subidas/' . $nombreArchivo;
                        move_uploaded_file($imagenCarpeta, $ruta);
                        if($res){
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" arial-label="close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                                </button>
                                Registro Insertado Exitosamente
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            
                            unlink("img/imagenes_subidas/".$nombreArchivo);
                        }
                        else{
                            ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                Error: <?php echo mysqli_error($con)?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Hay varios detalles. 1. no guardes la imagen en la BD. Guardala en un directorio y el path en la BD. 2. Guarda tambien un hash de la imagen (para comparar con facilidad y saber si subes una nueva) y eventualmente un registro de origen. 3. Cuando se recargue la página verifica los datos registrados, si ya están sigues derecho. 4. Antes de guardarla revisa que el tipo mime interno sea válido y que eventualmente no contenga código malicioso.

Comment: Me podrias explicar como podria realizar todos esos detalles por favor

Comment: @LPSoldier19 puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/291172/16597) sea lo que estas buscando.